# Application installation problem on iPhone with developer account

Tags: iphone, debugging, deployment

I am installing application on iPhone using developer certificates. When i install application it do not go ahead after default page. and if i exit the application and then i open application from iPhone then it works fine but the problem is that i have to use debugging and it is only possible when when app is running from XCode. so please help me. this is a big issue for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its solution is to update the xcode. when i updated my xcode my app start working good with iPhone.